# Add Simple Language Support to Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, vbscript, languageservice

I'm developing some VBScript using Visual Studio 2010.  The native support for this language isn't great, so going forwards I'm hoping to look into taking advantage of language services / VS Extensions to allow me to improve support for these languages.
For the moment however I just want to make my life simpler by adding a couple of features:

- Allow the VS Task List to recognise my ***'todo:*** comments
- Allow c# like ***#region...#endregion*** functionality to make it easy to break the script up into more easily readable blocks (to comply with VBScript I'd stick an apostrophe before the hash to make it a comment).

Is there a simple way to do this through configuration in VS, or do I have to create an entire language service to get this functionality?
What I'm asking may be impossible; but thought it worth asking on the off chance.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bet is you could do the tasklist stuff with a simple extension:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/163ba701%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

But to do the #region behavior I'm fairly certain you need a simple stripped out Language Service to get to the Source's AuthoringSink
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.package.authoringsink.addhiddenregion.aspx
and 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.package.authoringsink%28v=vs.90%29.aspx